# TrueNAS redundancy via multiple nodes rather than RAID?

Tags: truenas

Is it possible to setup TrueNAS to have data redundancy via multiple nodes and replications rather than via storing the data on a RAID device?

Currently I have a single system with a RAID setup. This system hosts TrueNAS with a SMB network share, and not much else.

I am wondering if the redundancy offered by RAID could be replaced with multiple devices (nodes?) each replicating a copy of the TrueNAS data.

I don't know if this is possible to do this at the system level, or possibly only the share level?

It would probably be better if it were setup this way rather than via RAID.

Comment: It appears so.  https://www.truenas.com/docs/core/coretutorials/tasks/creatingreplicationtasks/remotereplication/#starting-the-replication talks about ZFS replication. Note that this increases the risk sime data is lost [ie data not yet replicated]. There may also be performance implications as RAID can speed up IO

Comment: ZFS replication takes place beneath tje share level but abive the block level. I don't believe you can back up zvols - ie virtual block deviced with it, but it works on the whole filesystem - not shares (but Im not an expert)